# Array insert and excessive matches in nested for loops - ruby

Tags: ruby, nested-loops

I don't understand why, but I'm getting too many inserts and matches generated when I nest these two loops. Any help appreciated!

pseudocode
two arrays - nested for loops
search 2nd array for match of each element in 1st array
if there is a match in 2nd array, take the number after the match
insert number in 1st array after word that has been matched
end

problem code:

```
ary1 = ['a','b','c','d']
ary2 = ['e','f','g', 'a']


limit = ary1.count - 1
limit2 = ary2.count - 1

(0..limit).each do |i|
  (0..limit2).each do |j|
     if ary1[i] == ary2[j]
        ary1.insert(i,ary2[j])
        puts 'match!'
     end
  end 
end 

puts ary1
```

output:
match!
match!
match!
match!
a
a
a
a
a
b
c
d

provisional solution:

```
ary1 = ['a','b','c','d']
ary2 = ['e','f','g', 'a']
# have to make a copy to avoid excessive matches
ary_dup = Array.new(ary1)

limit = ary1.count - 1
limit2 = ary2.count - 1

(0..limit).each do |i|
  (0..limit2).each do |j|
     if ary1[i] == ary2[j]
        ary_dup.insert(i,ary2[j])
        puts 'match!'
     end
  end 
end 

puts ary_dup
```

output:
match!
a
a
b
c
d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because you're modifying array (ary1) under examination on the fly.

You could achieve desired result using this line of code -

```
(ary1 & ary2).each {|e| ary1.insert(ary1.index(e)+1,e)}
```

What it does is -

1. `ary1 & ary2` returns an array which is intersection of two arrays - ary1 and ary2. In other words it'll contain all those elements that exist in both arrays.
2. `.each` and ensuing block traverses over this new array and inserts each element in ary1 at `"index of original element" + 1`

`puts ary1 #=> ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d"]`

Comment: @Chris: nonocut's solution reflects the Ruby way of dealing with the problem.  Ruby generally offers many alternatives; another would be a.map {|e| b.include?(e) ? [e, e] : e}.flatten (assuming I understand the problem correctly).

Answer (score 0):

The below part is not correcrt:

```
(0..limit).each do |i|
  (0..limit2).each do |j|
     if ary1[i] == ary2[j]
        ary1.insert(i,ary2[j])
        puts 'match!'
     end
  end 
end
```

**First pass:**

```
ary1 = ['a','b','c','d']
ary2 = ['e','f','g', 'a']
```

when `limit=0` and `limit2 = 3`,there is a match.`ary1.insert(0,ary2[j])` line makes your array `ary1` as `ary1 = ['a','a','b','c','d']`

**Second pass:**

```
ary1 = ['a','a',b','c','d']
ary2 = ['e','f','g', 'a']
```

when `limit=1` and `limit2 = 3`,there is a match.`ary1.insert(1,ary2[j])` line makes your array `ary1` as `ary1 = ['a','a','a','b','c','d']`.

And it Goes on.. So as your `arr1`is having size *4*, 4 `a` s has been added to `ary1`. Finally it becomes - `[ a,a,a,a,a,b,c,d]`.

[**`Array#insert`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-insert) says :-

> *Inserts the given values before the element with the given index.Negative indices count backwards from the end of the array, where -1 is the last element.*

Comment: You forgot to add the second 'a' to ary1 under 'Second pass:'.